# Resize Element If It Moves Onto New Line

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image

On http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/picture-test/ I have two images side by side. The two images have different height to width ratios. I wanted both images to have the same height so gave the images different widths. I used the padding bottom hack to get the images height and width to always stay proportional.

To do this I added the following to the CSS file

```
    .wrapper-133percent-grampians {
    width: 33.9%;
    float: left;}


.wrapper-75percent-grampians {
    width: 60.1%;
    float: left;
}

.wrapper-133percent-grampians .inner {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 133%;
    height: 0;
}

.wrapper-75percent-grampians .inner {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 75%;
    height: 0;
}

.element-to-stretch-grampians {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The HTML code is as follows

```
<div class="wrapper-133percent-grampians" style="min-width: 172px;">
<div class="inner"><img class="element-to-stretch-grampians alignleft" src="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/venus-baths-test2-225x300.jpg" alt="venus baths test2" /></div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper-75percent-grampians"  style="min-width:172px;" >
<div class="inner"><img class="element-to-stretch-grampians alignnone" src="http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/IMGP0038-300x225.jpg" alt="IMGP0038" /></div>
</div>
```

I have the 'min:width:172px' statement because I wanted the two images to appear on top of each other when being displayed on mobile devices. When the images were being displayed side by side on mobile devices the images were too small.

When the images appear on top of each other they are 172px wide, yet the width of the mobile browser could be larger than 172px. I do not want to have white space on the mobile browser. How can I instruct the images to occupy the full width of the device WHEN the two images move onto separate lines.

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

This is because you have defined the width as 33% here

```
.wrapper-133percent-grampians {
    width: 33.9%;
    float: left;
}
```

Now I understand that you want the width to be 33% for desktop PC. But the same is being applied to mobile as well. You can separate both by defining different sized for different screen sizes

```
//for desktop applications
@media screen and (max-width: 499px) {
    .wrapper-133percent-grampians {
        width: 80%;
        float: left;
    }
}

//for mobile devices
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    .wrapper-133percent-grampians {
        width: 33.9%;
        float: left;
    }
}
```